# adding event handler to a dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a button in c# codebehind and am trying to add event listener to it, but the problem is if I use:

```
    {
        HtmlGenericControl dodaj = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
        dodaj.InnerText = "something";
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("type", "submit");
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("onclick","addKosarica");
        newDivInfo.Controls.Add(dodaj);
        sadrzaj.Controls.Add(newDivInfo);
        this.Controls.Add(sadrzaj);
    }

    protected void addKosarica(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("www.google.com");  //just to see if it triggers
    }
```

I get:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: addKosarica is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Tried googling the error, it is regarding javascript...

Then after googling some more, I tried:

```
    {
        Button dodaj = new Button;
        dodaj.Text = "something";
        dodaj.Click += new EventHandler("addKosarica");
        newDivInfo.Controls.Add(dodaj);
        sadrzaj.Controls.Add(newDivInfo);
        this.Controls.Add(sadrzaj);
    }

    protected void addKosarica(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("www.google.com");//just to see if it triggers
    }
```

and i get

> "Control 'ctl07' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag
>   with runat=server."

This is my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="11001.aspx.cs" Inherits="_11001" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

(its not much because i add everything dynamically and everything works except button onclick handler...)

Please, could someone tell me how to make this working...

EDIT: 
sadrzaj is a div that contains all this elemnts I'm adding.
I'm adding them in a function that is being called from Page_Load()

Comment: Where is your `form` tag? Is there one on your master page? As the error says, your button will need to be inside a form tag.

Comment: @CalC Form tag is in master page, inside of a body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button dodaj = new Button();
            dodaj.Text = "Click Me!";
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("type", "submit");
        dodaj.Attributes.Add("onclick", "addKosarica");
        newDivInfo.Controls.Add(dodaj);
        dodaj.Click += Dodaj_Click1;
    }

    private void Dodaj_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Ok");
    }
```

aspx code

```
<div runat="server" id="newDivInfo">
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. The problem was that the dynamically created div wasnt in the form part (dont know why, figured it out in "inspect element" mode), but now that i found out a proper way to make it working i managed to create it all dynamically!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you are very confused between a button server side and a button client side.

First question is: why don't you add the button in aspx?

Do you need to loop on a collection and create many similar button? You can use Repeater.

Then, reading your code... You have a master page (I hope containing a tag form `runat="server"`). You have to add the ID to the control to add.

In the first piece of code you have created onclick client side (so javascript) using

```
dodaj.Attributes.Add("onclick","addKosarica");
```

So you can remove:

```
protected void addKosarica(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("www.google.com");//just to see if it triggers
}
```

and add a function addKosarica() in aspx file.

In the second piece of code the correct code is:

```
dodaj.Click += myButton_Click;
```

and the right event is

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and you can create automatically in Visual Studio clicking tab twice after +=

I suggest also to not to use this.Controls directly: it's referred to page. You can add a PlaceHolder control or a Panel control in the Content tag and add Controls to it. If you use `this` and not a `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`, try to use `this.Form.Controls.Add`

You can referer to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c--net

Comment: well, i have more stuff in the div with the button and this is the only way to make it look like i want to. i need the function to be in codebehind because it will comunicate with database. i tried the second option with ur suggestion but the problem is that the page wont even load, it will throw the same "Control 'ctl07' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." error

Comment: Why not directly in aspx? The most common is:
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="Save" OnClick="myButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>

Comment: because i have h1, h2, label  and that button in the same div. if i create the button in aspx i don't know how to put it at the end of the div after the h1, h2 and the label. on other sites where i do it in aspx i use the syntax u wrote in the comment

Comment: You can write: <asp:Content...><div><h1>...</h1><h2>...</h2><asp:Label .../><asp:Button.../> Where is the problem?

Comment: problem is that h1 h2 and label texts are loaded from database

Comment: Ok. Can you add in your post what is: sadrzaj and in which event you are adding controls?

Comment: If you use `this` and not a `Panel` or `PlaceHolder`, try to use `this.Form.Controls.Add(sadrzaj);`