# Showing/hiding a div after datepicker date selection

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I want to show/hide a div when I select a date in the datepicker, or when the textbox associated changes its value.

I'm trying to intercept with jquery the selection, but it just won't fire. I attach some code to make myself clear.

Here's the html with the textbox and the datepicker div:

```
<div class='input-box margin-top10 div-data-and' data-role="data-input-div">
            <div class="icona calendario-img"></div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepartureDate, new
                {
                @class = "inp-data-and",
                placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayName(Resx.Index.DepartureDate).ToHtmlString()),
                data_role = "data-input",
                @readOnly = "true"
                })
        </div>
        <div class="ui-datepicker-div" data-role="data-div"></div>
```

Looks also like I can't use $ as selection for Jquery but I assume I can do with 'jq11' the same thing, seeing that this code below actually works:

```
jq11(document).ready(function () {
                init('@lcid');
                initLocalEvents();
                window.loader.hide();
                selectionTrigger('@ViewBag.Selection');
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding event handler to a dynamically created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225387/adding-event-handler-to-a-dynamically-created-button)

Comment: Where is your event handler? Could you please share your code which handles `change` event? Or is this you are looking for?

Comment: that's my problem there, using $ won't work, neither jq11, should I put my change event in the document ready?